# Environment specific build vs loading environment specific properties

Tags: java, deployment, build

One option for building is to package the environment-specific properties at build time (for example using maven profiles)

Another option is to set `-Denv=production` on your production environment, and on startup load the `/${env}/config.properties`. (spring allows that for example, but it can be done manually)

I've used both. The former means no additional environment configuration. The latter allows for using the same build on multiple environments.

The question: any other significant pros/cons, or is it virtually the same which approach will be chosen?

Related: [Load environment-specific properties for use with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204917/load-environment-specific-properties-for-use-with-propertyplaceholderconfigurer)

Comment: I tagged java, because my examples above are java-based. But language-agnostic answers are also welcome.

Comment: here we don't have the choice: we cannot put in PROD a *.war* that didn't get accepted in PREPROD.  And this must be the exact same *.war*.  We basically use "option 3", the one that "matt b" is using.  Btw we do not have access to the credentials of the production environments: so our *.war* knows where to find the config files, but we, developers, are not supposed to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion having different outputs per environment is a major downside, as it means you need to build N copies of the app, run the same build commands N times, etc. It's too easy to run into mistakes where you gave the "dev" version to the QA site, etc.

There's a bit of a third option in between which I am a fan of - storing the configuration values on the servers themselves, separate from the application, and the application then either is written to know where to find these configuration files or you have some sort of script which "re-configures" the app by replacing tokens in it's configuration files with the canonical values from the external files.

This way you can ship the same binary for all environments, and the external configurations can easily be placed under source control (for example, one file per environment) so changes can be audited, changes can be propagated automatically, etc.

This is also a convenient option if you work in a large organization where the developers are separate from the group that "operates" the application or is responsible for the different environments - since with this method, developers can know *what* to configure, but the other group is responsible for what *configuration values* to supply on each host.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 builds, one that generates the binary (a war file, without any server specific configuration) and another project which generates some property files for each environment environment. 
The deployment process takes the war and related configuration files and does its magic.

I don't think that shipping the configuration from all the environments in the binary is a good practice... but mostly because I think there's a chance of starting the app with the wrong option, and suddenly the dev application tries to connect to production.

Another thing is that some of the properties such as DB connection details or payment gateway password, are kept in a different configuration file which is owned by the operations / managed services team. As we don't want developers or rogue DBAs to go ballistic with the production DB.