# Spring - PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Select property file based on environment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to select the property context file based on the environment (dev, qa or prod) below is my bean configuration for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`,

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:**/config/handsOn-${proj.env}.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So how can i make spring framework to pick the right file based on the environment it is deployed.

I can able to get the environment based on the host it is deployed. Using below code,

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

Any help will be appreciated..!!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204917/load-environment-specific-properties-for-use-with-propertyplaceholderconfigurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i can able to package the required .properties based on the environment using maven profiles. I have used different profile for dev, qa and prod as below,

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
              <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dev-resources</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <!-- this is important -->
                                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                    <!-- target -->
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/config</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <!-- source -->
                                            <directory>${project.basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/config/dev</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do this.

1. Check out springs property injection. You can define properties in a pre-defined location and just make sure the right properties exist on the right box <util:properties location="${path.to.properties.file}"/>
2. If you don't want to do that, think about injecting the environment type as a JVM argument (e.g. -Denv.type=PROD) or something similar. You can then use this property in spring. Check out [How do I read JVM arguments in the Spring applicationContext.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598217/how-do-i-read-jvm-arguments-in-the-spring-applicationcontext-xml) on how to do that.

Comment: Currently i am injecting the property via JVM argument. But when i deploy in apache tomcat or WAS 7 server i am not sure how to pass this JVM argument.

Comment: Previously i used ant script to move the content from handOn-dev.properties to handsOn.properties file. But now since i migrated it to maven i am looking is there is any way to do the same in Maven.

Comment: In tomcat you can add a system property by setting it to  in the catalina.bat or catalina.sh just add it to SET JAVA_OPTS=-Denv=QA